# Php : generate at least one digit and one letter

Tags: php, random

How can I generate at least one digit and one letter with let's say 5 strings characters?

I know I can randomly generate digits and letters with this :

```
echo $rand = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
```

However, I've just checked it, and it can appear it only gives me simply 5 letters or 5 digits, and I'd like the rand to be always mixed with at least 1 digit and 1 letter.

Comment: you could pick the first letter and the first digit and put them together as you like. *or* just generate a random number in a range you like and express it as number or char and put them together again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure that $rand contains at least 1 digit and 1 letter, add checking. And then, for example, generate until success:

```
while ( !preg_match('/[0-9]/', $rand) && !preg_match('[a-z]',$rand )) { $rand = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5) };
```

Comment: Thank you for you help !